# Silverlight, VisualStateManager gotostate doesn't work with datatemplates

Tags: silverlight, visualstatemanager

I have a button with name "PART_closeButton" inside ContentPresenter. I am defining some visual states for my button.

```
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
          <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_closeButton" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                 </Storyboard>
          </VisualState>
          <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                  <Storyboard>
                       <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PARTcloseButton" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                  </Storyboard>
           </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
```

So everything is working for me. When I mouse over on button it becomes semitransparent.
But if I load some datatemplate for contentpresenter which also contains button with that same name, visual states does not react anymore. (mouseOver event is handled for that button also and it fires). 
goToState is not working.
I know that actual button object is changing, VisualState is connected with button with TargetName. So new button have the same name, why statemanager is not working ?